# How to convert a raster file (*.tif) into a composite geodataset by using Python in ArcGIS 10.2.1

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, geotiff-tiff, error-000860

I created geotiff rasters (approximately 6000 rasters) in .tif format by using Matlab Mapping Toolbox. When I examined the properties of the data, I realised that it is 64 bit double type. I need to create a batch process to extract values by using points and my code gave an error about the type of the data. (Error code 000860)

So it is obvious that I should use composite geodatasets in my process. Therefore I tried to convert them into composite geodatasets by using Composite Bands tool. When I used it for a sample data (which is opened in the table of contents) I was successful. But using this tool in a batch process gives an error which is:

**Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 22, in    File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 12855, in CompositeBands     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000271: Cannot open the input datasets Failed to execute (CompositeBands).**

My code is given below:

```
import arcpy
import os
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

mainfolder= "D:/csvfiles"
templateshp="D:/shp/station.shp"  
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

for foldername1 in os.listdir(mainfolder):
    insidefolder=mainfolder+foldername1
    for foldername2 in os.listdir(insidefolder):
        insidefolder2=insidefolder+"/"+foldername2
        arcpy.env.workspace = insidefolder2
        for filename in os.listdir(insidefolder2):
            if filename.lower().endswith(".tif"):
                filename2=filename.replace(".csv.tif","")
                fullname=insidefolder2+"/"+filename
                fullout1=insidefolder2+"/"+filename2+".img"
                fullout2=insidefolder2+"/"+filename2+".shp"
                print "Raster Composite:" + fullout1
                arcpy.CompositeBands_management(fullname,fullout1+".img")
                print "Point conversion:" + fullout2
                ExtractValuesToPoints(templateshp,fullout1,fullout2,"NONE","VALUE_ONLY")
                print "OUTPUT: "+fullout
                for z in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
                    arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df , z)
print "DONE!!!!"
```

What may be the problem is?

By the way, I am using ArcGIS 10.2.1.

Comment: One and a half year passed and I couldn't solve this issue. The main problem here is the raster output is 64 bit double. I believe Esri solved this issue in ArcGIS Pro, but I had no chance to try it. If anyone else encounters this kind of problem, trying the same process in ArcGIS Pro can be a solution.